# The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later

Tags: process, server, request, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have an Application developed in Worklight 6.1 and I upgraded the application to Mobile first 7.1. I have build and deployed the application in Mobile first 7.1. 
But my application Not able to invoke the adapter and displayed the Message "The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later"
I have followed the below procedure for up gradation.

```
   1. Installed the Mobile first 7.1 Plugin in Eclipse
   2. Imported the Existing 6.1 project in to My work space(I hope Tool will  
      auto upgrade app to 7.1)
   3. Build the application and it generated .war, .wlapp and .adapter files
   4. we have installed the standalone 7.1 Server.
   5. Deployed the build files in servers.
   6. Created the apk and installed in Mobile.
```

Now it is showing the Message  "The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later" while launching the application.
From the logs i found the below details when i try to invoke adapter
invocationContext: null
 Status           : 404
invocationResult : undefined

Note: It was working well in development environment

Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

It'd be more useful to see the complete server and client logs as well. Please upload and edit the question with links to the log files.

That said, in step 6 (*Created the apk and installed in Mobile.*) you do not mention if you have re-built the project with the correct remote server host, port and context root values. Make sure you've done that. See [The Build Settings and Deploy Target command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_building_and_deploying_build_settings_deploy_target.html).

Comment: Dear Idan, Thank you for your response. I have rebuilt the application with my staging domain details. In client side Logs i found that WL.Client.Connect function getting failed and jumping to onFailure section. I am not getting any server side logs why because app not even connecting server.

Comment: Well, print out the error object you get as part of the failure for a possible reason why it fails...

Comment: I tried to print the Failure object but it is printing like [object Object]. can you please suggest the parameters of failure object

Comment: Did you jsonstringify it?

Comment: Hi Idan, thank you for response. I got below status for failure object               [INFO:CONSOLE(20)] "Failure Object  : {"status":500}", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/main.js (20)

Comment: Look, it seems you're not able to properly explain your issue. I suggest that you will simply open a PMR and provide to the support team everything so that they could reproduce your problem.